# Updating Keywords in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, keyword, rank

First off I am not a coder or programmer and this site has helped me out many times over the years finding answers to my questions.

I am using a Wordpress SEO plugin called Rank Math and it appears to be doing a good job but it has a feature in its SEO settings called, Focus Keyword, that creates a Keyword for each post.

I  can enter a Focus Keyword by hand to test it but my site currently has over 18,000 post on it so doing this by hand just is not possible.

What I want to do is copy the title from the post and put it into the Focus Keyword field.

On Rank Math's site they posted this script to move tags into the Focus Keyword field but what I want instead of tags is to copy the title of the post and put it into the Focus Keyword field.

```php
function update_focus_keywords() {

    $posts = get_posts(array(

    'posts_per_page'    => -1,

    'post_type'     => 'post' //replace post with the name of your post type

    ));

    foreach($posts as $p){

        if(get_the_tags($p->ID)){

            foreach((get_the_tags($p->ID)) as $tag) {

                $keywords[] = strtolower($tag->name);

            }

        update_post_meta($p->ID,'rank_math_focus_keyword',implode(", ", array_unique($keywords)));

        }

    }
    
}

add_action( 'init', 'update_focus_keywords' );
```

What changes would I need to make to this script to accomplish copying the title of a post into the field for Focus Keyword.

Is there a simpler way such as using a SQL command? I have not been able to find anything to date.

Thank you in advance for any help anyone can provide.

Comment: "*Is there a simpler way such as using a SQL command*? Never update the database of Wordpress (or any system) directly unless its absolutely unavoidable! The system functions are the safest way to make changes. I was going to answer but you got another answer in the meantime that should work, so give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

I made changes in your example

```
function update_focus_keywords($offset = 0, $number = 100) {
    $posts = get_posts(array(
        'offset' => $offset,
        'posts_per_page' => $number,
        'post_type' => 'post'
    ));
    $count_posts = count($posts);

    foreach($posts as $p) {
        update_post_meta($p->ID,'rank_math_focus_keyword', $p->post_title);
        $offset++;
    }

    if($count_posts === $number) {
        update_focus_keywords($offset);
    }
}

add_action( 'init', 'update_focus_keywords' );
```

Now script take post title and put it into the Focus Keyword field.

Comment: FightInGlory, I thank you for your help but when I put your code into the snippet plugin and activated the snippet it crashed my site and show a critical flaw.

Comment: Check the debug.log file to see what the problem is, David: [Debugging in WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/).

Comment: I tested code before submit. Go to function.php and add this code. On home page make refresh and check result.

Comment: This is the error I got after running it several times: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /home/dtbcinci/public_html/wp-includes/meta.php on line 960

Comment: Is it trying to update all 18,000 post at one time?

Comment: I made changes in my answer. Please try again. Now script will take by 100 posts.